# Why does the program print 0 instead of the average?

Tags: c++

Wrote a function that calculates the average length of words in a sentence.
Why does the program print 0 instead of the average?
Please help me fix my mistake.

If you know how to make an implementation in one function, please write.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int CountWordsAndLetters(char* str, int& words, int& letters)
{
    words = 0;
    int i = 0;
    letters = 0;

    while (str[i] == ' ')
        i++;

    for (; str[i]; i++) {
        if (((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z'))
            || ((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z')))
            letters++;
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            words++;
            while (1)
                if (str[i] == ' ')
                    i++;
                else {
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    words = words + 1;
    return (words);
}

float AverageLetters(float words, float letters)
{
    float a = (double)(letters / words);
    return a;
}

int main()
{

    char array[255];
    int words = 0;
    int letters = 0;

    cout << "Enter the string\n\n";
    gets_s(array);
    int size;
    for (size = 0; array[size]; size++)
        ;
    char* str = new char[size];

    CountWordsAndLetters(str, words, letters);

    cout << "\nAverage number of letters per word: "
         << AverageLetters(words, letters);

    return 0;
}
```

If you know how to make an implementation in one function, please write.

Comment: I recommend you learn about the standard [character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification), like [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha).

Comment: Your code invoke *undefined behavior*. You use the uninitialized "string" `str` when calling `CountWordsAndLetters`. What use is `str`? Why can't you pass `array` to the function instead?

Comment: `if (((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z')) || ((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z')))` --> `if (isalpha(str[i]))`

Comment: do not use standard functions

Comment: *do not use standard functions* -- Why not?  Your method of determining if a character is alphabetic will not work if the language is not English or if the collating sequence is not ASCII.  If you got those orders from your teacher, then your teacher is teaching horrendous C++.

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, you also want `((double)letters) / words`

Comment: Yes, this is our C ++ to go through the pain. is it possible to fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are allocating an uninitialized array of char:

```
char* str = new char[size];
```

You put nothing in it.

You then pass it to `CountWordsAndLetters`:

```
//       here -------v
CountWordsAndLetters(str, words, letters);
```

You should consider simply sending `array` instead:

```
CountWordsAndLetters(array, words, letters);
```

Here's a [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/as6fx34Pr) of your code working.